# IOS Parallax and PageControll

Tags: ios, parallax, uipagecontrol

I am looking for any library that help me with make controller with parallax effect.

I need map on the top (my first controller) and page control on bottom, scrollable top with parallax effect and right and left with standard effect.

Any idea how to make this?

It is the same affect that Google Maps App (when look for  places).

Comment: I don't know any lib to do this. But I've found some great samples to make those effect. Take a look at http://www.thinkandbuild.it/implementing-the-twitter-ios-app-ui/. I hope it'll help you.

Answer (score -1):

Hi if you would like to have parallax effect on you're view. You should use  `UIMotionEffects`. This API will give you're opportunity to set nice and easy to manage parallax effect. Keep in mind that image for parallax should be a bit more bigger than original.

```
// Set vertical effect
UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *verticalMotionEffect = 
  [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] 
  initWithKeyPath:@"center.y"
             type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis];
verticalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-10);
verticalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(10);

// Set horizontal effect 
UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *horizontalMotionEffect = 
  [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] 
  initWithKeyPath:@"center.x"     
             type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];
horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-10);
horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(10);

// Create group to combine both
UIMotionEffectGroup *group = [UIMotionEffectGroup new];
group.motionEffects = @[horizontalMotionEffect, verticalMotionEffect];

// Add both effects to your view
[myBackgroundView addMotionEffect:group];
```

Comment: YES, but it isn't effect that I can.